# How to get last record from the latest inserted record

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table like this

```
Col1   Col2  Mindate                        MaxDate 
A       B    12-04-2012 00:12:00:087        31-04-2012 00:00:01:001
C       D    01-01-2011                     30-01-2011 
A       B    09-05-2012                     27-05-2012
A       B    11-07-2012                     21-07-2012
```

I have only inserted datetime in first row but omitied in other rows for brevity, all date columns are datetime.

Assume that I have inserted the last records for A and B (Col1 and Col2 are combined key).
Now I want last record for A amd B based on the mindate which in above case should be

```
A       B    09-05-2012                     27-05-2012
```

I am trying the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Col1 ='A' AND Col2='B' AND ....
```

Comment: Isn't July after May? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT Col1, Col2, Mindate, MaxDate
    , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1, Col2 ORDER BY Mindate DESC)
   FROM dbo.Tbl
   WHERE COL1='A' AND COL2='B'
)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Mindate, MaxDate
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 2
```

This would return the second last record according to Mindate and the given key.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the table by Mindate in descending order and get the record corresponding to rank 2.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM
    table t1
    JOIN (SELECT Col1, Col2, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Mindate DESC) 'Rank' 
          FROM table
          WHERE Col1 = 'A' AND col2 = 'B'
    ) as t2
ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2 AND t1.rank = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very good on performance but should do the job

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
WHERE Col1 ='A' AND Col2='B'
AND mindate = (select max(mindate) from tbl where Col1 = 'A' AND Col2='B')
```

Comment: But this will give me the last record of the table for A and B I want second last

Comment: Mmm... in the inner query you could add a where mindate <= last_inserted_date. Is this possible or not?

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Col1 ='A' AND Col2='B' AND Mindate = MAX(Mindate)
```

Comment: But this will give me the last record of the table for A and B I want second last

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Col1 ='A' AND Col2='B' AND Mindate < MAX(Mindate) LIMIT 1

Comment: This query will give error. Did you test it before posting?